The relationship between "reserve" and "iterator" with std::vector
When using the reserve() method with this iterator object, the program produces an unexpected error.
When I use the reserve() method without it, it works as expected, but when I use iterator, it doesn’t work at all.
the code that works:
vector <int> nums{1,2,3,4,5}, numsT{};

numsT.reserve(50);
numsT.insert(numsT.begin(), nums.begin(), nums.end() - 1);

The code that does not work:
vector <int> nums{ 1,2,3,4,5 }, numsT{};
vector <int>::iterator first{ nums.begin() }, last{ nums.end() - 1 }, position{ numsT.begin() };
 
numsT.reserve(50);
numsT.insert(position, first, last);


std::vector::reserve: _"If new_cap is greater than capacity(), all iterators (including the end() iterator) and all references to the elements are invalidated. "

What you have learned today, is that whenever you use a method from a standard library class you should ALWAYS first read its documentation on cppreference. And double so before posting a question here. SO requires at least a minimum of research effort (see hover text of the down button next to the score of the question).  And reading documentation is the bare minimum.

@PepijnKramer naturally I am very much in favor of reading the documentation. But keep in mind cppreference by itself can be a bit overwhelming for beginners. That is why I try to add some "down to earth" explanations in my answers in addition to quotes from cppreference.

@wohlstad Good reminder for me... I sometimes take that skill (reading docs) for granted

Welcome to StackOverflow @TheGrid. Please see: What should I do when someone answers my question?.

TL;DR:
The problem has nothing to do with the fact that you use the iterator type explicitly, but only with the fact that you initialize it before calling reserve.
More info:
Regarding the 2nd snippet:
As you can see in the std::vector::reserve documentation:

If new_cap is greater than capacity(), all`iterators (including the
end() iterator) and all references to the elements are invalidated.

In your case you initialize position as numsT.begin(), but then reserve numsT with 50 elements. Since it was empty it is almost certain that the new capacity (at least 50) exceeds the exisiting one, and so position is invalidated.
Therefore the subsequent call to:
numsT.insert(poistion, first, last);

Invokes undefined behavior, since position is not valid.
It will work if you initialize first after the call to reserve:
vector<int> nums{ 1,2,3,4,5 }, numsT{};
vector<int>::iterator first{ nums.begin() }, last{ nums.end() - 1 };
numsT.reserve(50);
vector<int>::iterator position{ numsT.begin() };
numsT.insert(position, first, last);

The reason the 1st snippet works:
In the first snippet you call insert with numsT.begin(). It is evaluated at this point when reserve already took place and is therefore valid.

A side note:
It is better to avoid using namespace std; - see more about it here.

cppreference says:

If new_cap is greater than capacity(), all iterators (including the end() iterator) and all references to the elements are
invalidated.

So, if a reallocation happens (which is the case here) the iterator position is no longer valid. A call to numsT.begin() would return a different value after the reserve.
